# Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 restarting after shutdown - can't shutdown

Tags: server, 18.04, shutdown

I can't shutdown Ubuntu Server 18.04.3, I've tried every solution I can find online (and there seem to be a number of people with this problem!) 
If I attempt to shut down, the machine will turn back on within 5s or so, All my "Wake on" options in the BIOS are off, wake on LAN from Ubuntu is off.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, nor how to stop it, I've added various ACPI options to Grub, turned off and on WOL, no difference. nothing seems to keep this machine off :(

It's an old core2duo running on a gigabyte EP45-DSL3 motherboard with the latest (11b) BIOS

Can anyone help?